# Android Interacting Thread and Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, interface

I have MainActivity extends Activity

and I start thread in MainActivity
the thread called ThreadHandler extends thread

without "activity.showMessage(s);"
it works totally fine

and this is run method

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Log.i("ThreadHandelr","running");
    while(true){
        try {
            String s = streamIn.readUTF();
            activity.showMessage(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity there is method called

```
public synchronized void showMessage(String s){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,0).show();
}
```

I made constuctor for ThreadHandler that passed MainActivity
to use showMessage method
but I got an error
"threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception"
"FATAL EXCEPTION: THREAD-124"

Sorry for bad grammar because the english is not my first language tt

Conclusion
How do you use MainActivity method in thread "run"

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to interact with any UI components from other threads. This means changing your code to something like

```
final String s = streamIn.readUTF();
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        activity.showMessage(s);
    }

});
```